# install build-essential without apt and without internet in linux 3.4.7

Tags: linux, root

I want to install build-essential on linux server, where apt command is not found. 
Im not able to connect internet over the server.
I found some solutions, but all of them included apt-get, which I cant use.

Comment: What distribution are you running? Use the appropriate package management utility of that distribution. Otherwise you'll have to find a way to manually unpack/install/compile said package.

Comment: The Debian "build-essential" is mainly `g++, make` .... and g++ dependencies: `gcc, libc-dev`. Besides that the essentials package contains a text file with "recommended" → `autoconf` etc. https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential